# NetSuite Rest Integration - Get Sales Records By Date

Tags: api, netsuite

I need direction on how I would get the sales transactions from NetSuite for a given date range and then access the details (such as customer information) and sale amount.  Are there a set of APIs best for this or a RestLet approach/sample I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

Queries are done through the search API. You would want to perform a search, and then export its results. You can create a restlet that accepts some parameters by which to search as input and exports search results as output. The restlet would be implemented in javascript (in NetSuite's SuiteScript).

The following code is quick pseudocode with some SuiteScript 2..0, just to help you get started. This is not something you can copy paste, and this is off the top of my head, you will need to still do some research.

```js
var orderSearch = search.create({
  type: 'salesorder',
  filters: [
    ['mainline', 'is', true],
    'AND',
    ['trandate', 'on', '9/25/2020']
  ], 
  columns: [
    search.createColumn({ name: 'entity' }),
    search.createColumn({ name: 'trandate'}),
    search.createColumn({ name: 'total' })
  ]
});

var firstPageOfResults = [];
var pages = orderSearch.runPaged({ pageSize: 100 });
if (pages && pages.count > 0) {
  var page = pages.fetch({ index: 0 });
  firstPageOfResults = page;
}

// here is where you do something like return the search results 
// to the output of the restlet function
return firstPageOfResults;
```

So, again, this is just quickly drafted rough code to get you started.

You will need to learn more about the search operators, you might want "between" instead of "on", so you can express some other start date and some other end date.

You can of course return other fields of sales orders, you need to go look up the fields in the "record browser" help section.

And you can learn more about the search API in the netsuite docs on writing suitescript.

You will also need to learn about setting up a restlet. Also, if you plan to call your restlet from outside NetSuite, you need to learn about how to setup token based authentication and an "integration record" in netsuite so that you can get basically a password-like thing to pass in the Authorization header to securely call the restlet.

---

There are more advanced ways of doing all this stuff. You can also learn about and use `SuiteQL`. I am not going to go into detail here. It is a way to write a query in SQL and run it. You might want to do that instead.